# Creating login form with SQLite in Codename One and Java

Tags: java, sqlite, netbeans, codenameone

I want to create a working login and registration form in Codename One using SQLite.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: We expect questions here to be preceded by prior research and an attempt. If it is urgent, then make a start urgently, and then _if_ you get stuck, ask a non-urgent question, with a detailed account of what you have done so far.

Comment: Your username has a spelling error in it, by the way - you may wish to correct that to "Programmer", with three Rs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this sample](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html) on auto generating UI and SQLite binding to Codename One.